# Is it haram for men to wear a chain?

Tags: halal-haram, men

Although on this site most people say no, I think it isn't. This is because in the hadith that is often quoted it says men are to not imitate women. But in this instance, in the modern day mostly men where chains and women wear necklaces. These are 2 different things. With this new information in mind, is it still haram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salam,

**Regarding the hadith:**

Men and women should not imitate each other
on the basis of their **biological** and social features with their *implications*; which is necessary to differentiate a person unambiguously in a society.

Imitation here does not mean that if men offer prayers, then women should not or if men eat food then women should not eat food and die in order to not imitate men.

For the *implications* of the biological roles of the two, consider this example: Men and women have different body anatomy, so their clothes shall be able to differentiate them and make their social and visual recognition more clear.

It shall be understood that the Shariah is only for legal and religious jurisprudence which aims to make the life more comfortable,easy, clean and guiding (except when implemented by those who don't have it's knowledge and run it under their wild interpretations ). So, it is advisable to not extend hadiths very literally in all aspects of life without a logical context.

God knows best !

Comment: bro, ans with y/n please. is it haram or halal for man?